# Java Applet fail / disappear when another frame is reloaded in IE10

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, internet-explorer-10

Does anyone face this problem?

Applet disappear when another frame is reloaded in IE10.
I found a related bug report in Java bug Database
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7193503

1. Any other solutions beside trigger repaint()?
2. By the way, how to vote the bug in Java Bug Database?

Answer (score 0):

> Any other solutions beside trigger repaint()?

3 posibilities jump to mind.

1. Launch the applet free-floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
2. Don't use frames.
3. Use an earlier version of IE, or a different UA.

> By the way, how to vote the bug in Java Bug Database?

Step one is to join the OTN.  Note that OTN members have complained about not being able to access the bug DB.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the posiblitites are not suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to trigger repaint() which still cannot solve the problem.
I think the components positions in applet are wrong after the frame is reloaded.

The workaround is resize the window by Javascript call.